# Laravel 9: One route auto-adding '/public/' to the URL

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-9

I'm running a website with Laravel 9. All my routes are mapping correctly, but one of them ("https://example.com/resources") inexplicably keeps adding "/public/" to the page's URL (e.g. "https://example.com/public/resources").

The page runs fine, but I obviously don't want "/public" in there.

All the pages with child URLs work without the "public" directory (e.g. "https://example.com/resources/locations"). I can't figure out why "public" keeps getting added to the "/resources" URL and only to that one.

I have run php artisan route:list with the following result:

```
  GET|HEAD   / ............................................................................................................ home
  POST       _ignition/execute-solution .......... ignition.executeSolution › Spatie\LaravelIgnition › ExecuteSolutionController  
  GET|HEAD   _ignition/health-check ...................... ignition.healthCheck › Spatie\LaravelIgnition › HealthCheckController  
  POST       _ignition/update-config ................... ignition.updateConfig › Spatie\LaravelIgnition › UpdateConfigController  
  GET|HEAD   api/user .............................................................................. generated::aJrGF7dIWENf1Kwl  
  GET|HEAD   company ................................................................................................... company  
  GET|HEAD   contact ................................................................................................... contact  
  GET|HEAD   contact/careers ................................................................................... contact-careers  
  GET|HEAD   contact/expert ..................................................................................... contact-expert  
  GET|HEAD   contact/quote ....................................................................................... contact-quote
  GET|HEAD   contact/survey ..................................................................................... contact-survey  
  GET|HEAD   contact/technical ............................................................................... contact-technical  
  GET|HEAD   contact/thank-you ................................................................................ contact-thankyou  
  GET|HEAD   industries ....................................................................................... industries-index  
  GET|HEAD   products ........................................................................................... products-index  
  GET|HEAD   products/ilh ......................................................................................... products-ilh  
  GET|HEAD   products/ils ......................................................................................... products-ils  
  GET|HEAD   products/ilt ......................................................................................... products-ilt  
  GET|HEAD   products/iltr ....................................................................................... products-iltr  
  GET|HEAD   projects ........................................................................................... projects-index  
  GET|HEAD   resources ......................................................................................... resources-index  
  GET|HEAD   resources/cv ......................................................................................... resources-cv  
  GET|HEAD   resources/locations ........................................................................... resources-locations  
  GET|HEAD   resources/login ................................................................................... resources-login  
  GET|HEAD   resources/privacy ............................................................................... resources-privacy  
  POST       resources/process ........................................... resources-process › ResourcesController@resourcesForm  
  GET|HEAD   resources/terms ................................................................................... resources-terms  
  GET|HEAD   resources/terms-detail ..................................................................... resources-terms-detail  
  POST       resources/terms/process .......................................... terms-process › ResourcesController@termsProcess
  GET|HEAD   resources/warranties ......................................................................... resources-warranties  
  GET|HEAD   sanctum/csrf-cookie ............................. sanctum.csrf-cookie › Laravel\Sanctum › CsrfCookieController@show  
  GET|HEAD   services ................................................................................................. services
```

Here is the group code from my web.php file:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'resources'], function() {
    Route::get('/', function() {
        return view('resources.index');
    })->name('resources-index');

    Route::get('locations', function() {
        return view('resources.locations');
    })->name('resources-locations');
    ...
}
```

My webserver is Apache v2.4.29 (Ubuntu)

The routing works fine locally using php artisan serve. It is only on the server where this is occurring.

Comment: Search for a htacess or the like

Comment: Yep, this is probably someone's old attempt at making Laravel work off the root. A `.htaccess` or Apache rewrite config somewhere is the likely culprit.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From what I can determine, my folder is the same name as the "resources" folder in Laravel. So even though it's a specified View, Laravel defaults to add "/public" to specify the difference.

Comment: That strikes me as unlikely, but if you can reproduce the behavior in a fresh Laravel install, you should report it as a bug to the development team.